# MarginLeft doesn't work: Why?

Tags: java, android, xml

i have this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/text"
        />
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to know why on some phones or versions of Android (2.3 Gingerbread mainly) the margins are pratically 0, in the sense that it is not detached from the left margin but it is attached, as if there were no android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:layout_gravity="left"` to your textView. Value of layout_gravity can be any of valid list.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your xml .I have added `android:layout_gravity="left"`

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="text"
            />
```